# how to map new indices of sparse matrix to old ones after slicing?

Tags: python, scipy

I have a following problem:

After applying Tf-Idf procedure to text data I have a sparse matrix with n rows and 250000 columns.

There are 2000 columns of special interest, so I slice the matrix:

```
new_matrix = old_matrix[:, needed_columns]
```

So I get matrix with n rows and 2000 columns. However I need somehow to map indices of columns of new_matrix to old ones. For instance, 0th column of new_matrix is 219th column of old_matrix, 1st is 926th, 2nd is 1004th and so on. Is there any way to do it?

Converting it to pandas or numpy unfortunately is not an option due to memory limits.

Answer (score 1):

That information is in `needed_columns`, which apparently had value `[29, 926, 1004, ...]`, so you can just look it up in there. No shuffling or sorting needed.

You can call it `original_columns` instead to make the code more readable.

Here is a simple example:

```py
import numpy as np

old_matrix = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])

original_columns = [1,2]

new_matrix = old_matrix[:,original_columns]

# index in new_matrix
i_new = 0
# index in old_matrix, shall be equal to '1'
i_old = original_columns[i_new]
```